# Isosceles triangle help

Tags: geometry

[image]

$\triangle{PQR}$ is an isosceles whose equal sides $PQ$ and $PR$ are $13$ $cm$ each, and the base $QR$ measures $10$ $cm$.
$PS$ is the perpendicular from $P$ to $QR$ and $O$ is a point on $PS$ such that $\angle{QOR}={90}^{\circ}$.
Find the area of shaded region.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried Area of triangle PQR=1/2 PS*QR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Pythagorean Theorem, the height of $\triangle PQR$ is $\sqrt{13^2-5^2}$. Now you can find the area of $\triangle PQR$.

We next calculate the area of $\triangle OQR$. This is made up of two right-angled isosceles triangles with legs $5$.

Comment: Thanks! I found the answer.

Comment: Your answer is good, as you always deliver high quality answers, but I almost feel that this question didn't deserve a full answer.

Comment: You are right, I looked at what I had written, and edited so as to leave OP some things to do. But not quickly enough!

Answer (score 0):

If two polygons are similar, the ratio of their areas is equal to the square of the ratio of their corresponding sides. Example: If the sides of two similar triangles are in the ratio of 3:5, find the ratio of their areas.